# Multiple jsons to csv

Tags: python, json, excel, csv

I have multiple files, each containing multiple highly nested json *rows*. The two first rows of one such file look like:

```
{
"u":"28",
"evv":{
       "w":{
            "1":400,
            "2":{
                 "i":[{
                       "l":14,
                       "c":"7",
                       "p":"4"
                       }
                     ]
                 }
           }
       }
}
{
"u":"29",
"evv":{
       "w":{
            "3":400,
            "2":{
                 "i":[{
                       "c":14,
                       "y":"7",
                       "z":"4"
                       }
                     ]
                 }
           }
       }
}
```

they are actually rows, I just wrote them here this way for more visibility.

My question is the following:

<del>Is there any way to convert *all* these files to one (or multiple, i.e. one per file) csv/excel... ?</del>

Is there any simple way, that doesn't require writing dozens, or hundreds of lines in Python, specific to my file, to convert *all* these files to one (or multiple, i.e. one per file) csv/excel... ? One example would be using an external library, script... that handles this particular task, regardless of the names of the fields.

The trap is that some elements do not appear in each line. For example, for the *"i"* key, we have 3 fields (l, c, p) in the first json, and 3 in the second one (c, y, z). Ideally, the csv should contain as many columns as possible fields (e.g. evv.w.2.i.l, evv.w.2.i.c, evv.w.2.i.p, evv.w.2.i.y, evv.w.2.i.z) at the risk of having (many) null values per csv row.

A possible csv output for this example would have the following columns:

```
u, evv.w.1, evv.w.3, evv.w.2.i.l, evv.w.2.i.c, evv.w.2.i.p, evv.w.2.i.y, evv.w.2.i.z
```

Any idea/reference is welcome :)

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible -- I recommend looking at python's [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) and [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules, and trying to write a script that does what you want yourself. Come back here if you get stuck and we'll help you debug your program.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what the csv file should contain for the example data and the code you're written to try to do it yourself.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff, I am aware of the existence of these two modules, and I know I can use them to do exactly what I want, even though it can be very cumbersome. My question is whether a script that does what I want has already been written before

Comment: Not likely. Those modules aren't that complicated, nor is your problem -- you can probably get this solved with a fairly small/easy script.

Comment: @martineau: done, thanks :)

HaydenSchiff: I will give it a try

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, with python all things are possible.

Comment: @RPGillespie question modified then.

Comment: There is no "standard" json to csv conversion formula. CSV is is a table layout, JSON can be any arbitrary structure. You need to figure out how you want to map your JSON to CSV and then do it. It would probably take 10 lines of code or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no general-purpose program that does precisely what you ask for.

You can, however, write a Python program that does it.

This program might do what you want. It does not have any code specific to your key names, but it is specific to your file format.

- It can take several files on the command line.
- Each file is presumed to have one JSON object per line.
- It flattens the JSON object, joining labels with "."

```
import fileinput
import json
import csv


def flattify(d, key=()):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        result = {}
        for i in d:
            result.update(flattify(i, key))
        return result
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        result = {}
        for k, v in d.items():
            result.update(flattify(v, key + (k,)))
        return result
    return {key: d}

total = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    if(line.strip()):
        line = json.loads(line)
        line = flattify(line)
        line = {'.'.join(k): v for k, v in line.items()}
        total.append(line)

keys = set()
for d in total:
    keys.update(d)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file = csv.DictWriter(output_file, sorted(keys))
    output_file.writeheader()
    output_file.writerows(total)
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks :)
I don't think this handles multiple entries in a list inside a json (example evv.w.2.i. One way to do so would be to create as many columns as needed for example : 

`   
 if isinstance(d, list):
            d = {str(i): j for i, j in enumerate(d)}
            return flattify(d, key=key)
`

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this (python3) solution works for you.

```
import json
import csv

with open('test.json') as data_file:
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
        for line in data_file:
            data = json.loads(line)
            output = [[data['u'], data['evv']['w'].get('1'), data['evv']['w'].get('3'),
                       data['evv']['w'].get('2')['i'][0].get('l'), data['evv']['w'].get('2')['i'][0].get('c'),
                       data['evv']['w'].get('2')['i'][0].get('p'), data['evv']['w'].get('2')['i'][0].get('y'),
                       data['evv']['w'].get('2')['i'][0].get('z')]]
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            a.writerows(output)
```

**test.json**

```
{   "u": "28",  "evv": {        "w": {          "1": 400,           "2": {              "i": [{                 "l": 14,                    "c": "7",                   "p": "4"                }]          }       }   }}
{"u":"29","evv":{       "w":{            "3":400,            "2":{                 "i":[{                       "c":14,                       "y":"7",                       "z":"4"                       }                     ]                 }           }       }}
```

**output**

```
python3 pyprog.py 
dac@dac-Latitude-E7450 ~/P/pyprog> more output.csv 
28,400,,14,7,4,,
29,,400,,14,,7,4
```